# Materialize css. How to add triangle in top of dropdown content

Tags: html, css, materialize

Does anyone know how to add an arrow to dropdovn content so that it appears first?
My problem is that when you add an arrow through the pseudo-element(to dropdown-content) or div with css, on button click first appears the dropdown content and then arrow shows(but arrow is placed on top of the content).

Here are examples:

```css
html{
  
  background: #000000;
}
.dropdown-content{
  margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
  overflow:inherit;
}

.dropdown-button::before {
  content: "▼";
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.dropdown-content:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    top: 0;
    right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col s12">
<a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-beloworigin='true' data-activates='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

  <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Fiddle also [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sj2tm8cd/20/).

Comment: Did you go with a particular solution? I'm curious to know what other options exist.

Comment: i get the solution with adding a overfllow inherit !important state to dropdown-content css. here is example https://jsfiddle.net/sj2tm8cd/38/

Comment: Nice, looks like it works with any overflow property other than "hidden". Too bad it has to use "!important".

Comment: Yeah that is bad solution,but i dont found any other(i open issue in github but(((( ). In framework there is a javascript animation,that opens the content.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ::after element behind the dropdown, like this:

```
    .dropdown-content:after{
        z-index: -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

Everything within the `.dropdown-content` element is not displaying, preventing pseudo classes from being applied up until the element is showing and the pseudo class takes a second to apply.

**Solutions**

1. Instead of "display:none" keep the `.dropdown-content` element visible, but move it off the screen and move it where it belongs when toggled on. This is how the Foundation Framework successfully adds the caret. Example: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/dropdown.html
2. Add an extra `<li>` at the beginning and give it a CSS image background resembling the caret.